# My node js API call is not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rethinkdb

I am new to Nodejs and RethinkDB.I just building Simple like function.If user clicks the Like button It will Increase the Like If they already Liked ,Like will removed.And Secure My API wit jwt Tokens,My problem is When user Clicks Like Button again and again .Like Just Increasing I don't Why this is Happening

```
app.post('/__h',(req,res) => {
    function deleteLike(username,name,postDbId) {
        r.connect({db:'image'}).then(conn => {
            r.table('posts').get(postDbId).update(
                {
                    whoLikedIt:r.row('whoLikedIt').filter(liked => {
                        return liked('username').ne(username)
                    })
                }
            ).run(conn).then(response => {

                if(response.replaced == 1){

                    r.table('posts').get(postDbId).update({
                        likesCount:r.row("likesCount").add(-1)
                    }).run(conn).then(response => {
                        console.log(response)
                        res.json({
                            isLiked:false
                        })

                    })
                    console.log(response)

                }else{
                    res.json({
                        isLiked:false
                    })

                }
            })
        })
    }
    function postLike(username,name,postDbId) {
       r.connect({db:'image'}).then(conn => {
            r.table('posts').get(postDbId).update(
                {whoLikedIt:r.row('whoLikedIt').append({name:name,username:username})}
            ).run(conn).then(response => {

                if(response.replaced == 1){

                    r.table('posts').get(postDbId).update({
                        likesCount:r.row("likesCount").add(1)
                    }).run(conn).then(response => {
                        console.log(response)
                        res.json({
                            isLiked:true
                        })

                    })

                }else{
                    res.json({
                        isLiked:false
                    })


                }
            })
        })
    }

    let isLoggedIn = req.cookies['check'];
    let token = req.cookies['peace'];

    if(isLoggedIn == "true"){
        if(token){
            jwt.verify(token,JWTPASS,(err,decode) => {
                if(err){
                    res.json({error:true})
                }else{
                   //Check is that Liked
                    let username = decode.user.username;
                    let name = decode.user.name;
                    let postDbId = req.body.data.postDbId;
                    r.connect({db:'image'}).then(conn => {
                        r.table('posts').get(postDbId).run(conn).then(response => {
                            // console.log(response);
                            if(response.whoLikedIt.length == 0){
                                console.log('No One Likes')
                             postLike(username,name,postDbId);


                            }else{
                                response.whoLikedIt.map(data => {
                                    if(data.username == username){
                                        console.log('Already Liked');

                                      deleteLike(username,name,postDbId)

                                    }

                                })
                            }


                        })
                    })
                }
            })
        }else{
            console.log('Dei')
            res.json({error:true});
        }
    }else{
        res.json({error:true});
        console.log('OMG')
    }
})
```